# React setState() after fetch not rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, setstate

I am **fetching** data in **componentDidMount()** *(I am getting them in the form I want)* and I want to save them in the **component state** with **this.setState**.
The state is not changing.

- I console log that I am getting to the point where setState is called - there are conditions
- I tried `const that = this`

The component is not re-rendering and state is not changing and I would like to know why.

My code:

```
export class Offers extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderOffer = this.renderOffer.bind(this);
        this.state = {
        ...
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState(() => ({
            offer: {},
            isLoading: true,
            isMyOffer: false,

            ...
        }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('MOUNTED');
        const { profile } = this.props;
        if (profile) {
            this.setState(() => ({
                isLoading: false
            }));
        }
        if (profile && profile._id) {
            this.setState(() => ({
                isMyOffer: true,
                ...
            }));

            fetch(`/api/offers-by/${profile._id}`,{
                method: 'GET'
            })
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(offers => {
               if(!offers || !offers.length) {
                   this.setState(() => ({
                   isLoading: false
                  })
                  );
              } else {
                  console.log('ELSE', offers[0]._id); // getting proper data
                  console.log('THIS', this) // getting this object 
                  const offerData = offers[0]
                  this.setState(() => ({
                      offer: offerData,
                      isLoading: false
                  })) //  then
              }}) // fetch
              console.log('STATE', this.state)
          }
          console.log('STATE', this.state)
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `setState` passing an object instead of a function?

Comment: I didn't and according to the react source code, it should not matter.

Comment: How do you know the state is not chaning ? If your debug attempt is through the `console.log(this.state)`  then your debug is wrong. The `fetch` is asynchronous so the state will not have changed yet (it will after the fetch completes and the `then` is executed*). But even if you logged the state in the `then` method again it would not work because `setState` is also asynchronous. Use the `setState` callback to log and see if the state changed.

Comment: I was using console log in render too so I saw there the state is not changing. My mistake didn't include this information in the question.

Comment: @AgataAndrzejewska the code you have posted should not exhibit the problem you describe (*if the `ELSE` and `THIS` logs are reached*). Are you sure there aren't other parts of your code that might be interfering with the state setting ? Any console errors/warning ? Can you post the whole component code (*and perhaps also a live version of it?*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thanks for the help, the code was in fact influenced by errors occurring while mounting component. So fetch worked but setState didn't on the unmounted component. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

setState has a callback method as the second argument.You should use that after the initial setState.This works because setState itself is an asynchronous operation.The setState() method does not immediately update the state of the component but rather if there are multiple setStates, they will be batched together into one setState call.

```
this.setState(() => ({
            isLoading: false
        }),() =>{
   /// You can call setState again here and again use callback and  call fetch and invoke setState again..
});
```

Ideally you could refactor some of your setStates into a single setState call.Start with an empty object and add properties to your object based on conditons.

```
const updatedState ={}
if(loading){
 updatedState.loading = false
}
if(profile &&..){
 updatedState.someProperty = value.
}

this.setState(updatedObject,()=> {//code for fetch..
}) // Using the object form since you don't seem to be in need of previous State.
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Your suggestions helped me find a solution.

Comment: Cool,glad to help